# Super simple JQuery Question - refresh static html

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following two functions that work great:

```
$(function(){
  $('.trash_can a.delete').live('click', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var link = $(this);
    $.post(link.attr('data-href'),
      {
        promo_id: link.attr('data-promo_id')
      },
      function(data) {
        $('#page').html(data.html);
      });
    console.log('Clicked Delete');
  });
});

$(function(){
  $('#add-mod-form').bind('ajax:success', function(evt, data, status, xhr){
      data = $.parseJSON(data); 
      // console.log(data.success);
     if (data.success == true) {
          $('#page').html(data.html);
          $('#page box_bc').html()
       }
       else {
       }
  });
});
```

As data is received for page, I would also like to reload a static html element,  $('#page box_bc') - How do I do this simple task with Jquery? Notice, i've tried it above, and that part does not work as planned.

Thanks

Comment: Why are you accessing `.attr('data-*')` instead of `.data('*')`?

Comment: `box_bc` is not a selector. You will need a valid selector if you want to achieve what you want. What does your markup look like?

Comment: please provide some HTML, is "box_bc" a tag name?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use:

```
var $dataHtml=$(data.html);
$('#page box_bc').html($('#page box_bc',$dataHtml));
```

Answer (score 0):

It is not very clear to me what you are trying to achieve. If the element is static what is the point trying to refresh it ? In case its content somehow depends on other elements of page : then it has to be reconstructed. 
The code you have written fails because :

`$('...').html()` 

returns the html content of that element. It does not do anything to the content. Probably it would be better if you could elaborate more on the context and purpose of the code.

Comment: Its not necessarily static. There is embedded ruby code. So the point is to run Ruby logic that might not be relevant to JQuery folks

Comment: If you are interested, the logic counts the amount of comments, and displays a form if the comments is less than 3 and hides it if is greater than 3.

Comment: Whatever ruby code was embedded was parsed and processed on the server before the page was dispatched to the client. Once the page has been delivered to the client refreshing a particular part of page (as @DarmRet has suggested) is definitely not going to result in re-processing of ruby code. The only to have ruby code re-processed to re-fetch that part from server through an ajax request.